# Are static objects shared among tests when they run simultaneously in Visual Studio? If so, how to prevent?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, testing, static, resharper

While I was thinking it is is memory efficient to make large objects static, I was just told that using static objects should be prevented because in Visual Studio you can't control which tests are running and tests might run simultaneously. Meaning that the static object could be accessed and/or manipulated by multiple tests at the same time.

Is there a way to prevent that from happening? I found [ThreadStaticAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threadstaticattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0) but it seems to only work for field variables.

Comment: Unit tests should be repeatable and able to run in any order. If you use (modify) a static shared object then this will not be the case. Read only object would be okay though. You need to give much more information about your scenario to get any helpful answers to your question. Why have you tagged ReSharper?

Comment: I tagged resharper because that is what we use to run tests. I thought maybe running tests (simultaneously) works different using that extension.

Comment: what do you mean shared static object? that sounds like the sharing is a separate property you can switch on and off

Comment: Also, remember [this](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/): do you have an actual problem with your tests in terms of memory?